# Grommet Split children issues("Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Split`, expected an array.")

Tags: reactjs, grommet

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Split`, expected an array.

I am getting this warning in my console, for following code,

```
<Split>
  <Box colorIndex='neutral-1'
    justify='center'
    align='center'
    pad='medium'>
    Left Side
  </Box>

</Split>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple warning for Grommet Split tag, there must be two children tags inside split tag

i.e

```
<Split>
  <Box colorIndex='neutral-1'
    justify='center'
    align='center'
    pad='medium'>
    Left Side
  </Box>
  <Box colorIndex='neutral-2'
    justify='center'
    align='center'
    pad='medium'>
    Right Side
  </Box>
</Split>
```

if any of box tag is missing, console with have this warning,

> "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object`
>   supplied to `Split`, expected an array."